# R plot with multiple lines ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
dput(data)

structure(list(Anno = c(2015L, 2014L), Gennaio = c(381, 270.9
), Febbraio = c(355, 266.75), Marzo = c(352, 285.5), Aprile = c(323, 
288), Maggio = c(296, 288), Giugno = c(307, 276.17), Luglio = c(340, 
298.75), Agosto = c(335, 307.5), Settembre = c(304, 307.5), Ottobre = c(283, 
342.5), Novembre = c(281, 401.25), Dicembre = c(274, 387.5)), .Names = c("Anno", 
"Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", 
"Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I would like to plot this with multiple lines, gruped by Year (Anno). How can i do that? Something like this:
[image]

I tried this:

```
data.melted <- melt(data, id.vars="Anno", value.name="Mese", variable.name="Anno")
ggplot(data=data.melted, aes(x=Anno, y=Mese, group = Anno, colour = Anno)) +
+     geom_line() +
+     geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

But i get this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : oggetto "Mese" non trovato
```

Comment: add a `geom_line()` or `geom_smooth(se = F)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

melt(data, "Anno", variable.name = "Mese") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Mese, y = value, color = as.factor(Anno))) + 
    geom_point(size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
    geom_line(aes(group = Anno))
```

The piping using `dplyr` `%>%` operator is of course optional. You can save intermediate steps as you did in your code.

The result is the following plot:
[image]

Comment: I get this error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : oggetto "Mese" not found"

Comment: Did you use the code I posted? I do not get the same error.